# Appending multiple CSV files and creating a new column with the filename in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to work with pandas library if there a way possible to make the filename as a column name 
for example, my files names are with dates.

```
stock_2019-10-11.csv,
stock_2019-11-11.csv.
```

I want to make 2 different columns with the filenames and get the append the values 
something I expect to get out a CSV file as :

```
   coulmns-primary_key, article_numerber,stock_2019-10-11,stock_2019-11-11

data-0   101,201,4,2
data-1   102,301,5,2
```

something like above, the new columns have values coming in from the CSV's merged.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import sys
import csv

data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes
for csv in globbed_files(my directiry of files):
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv,encoding='utf_16',error_bad_lines=False,index_col=False)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    data.append(frame)

frame1 = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True
```

)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: What is the structure of each csv file you are loading?

Comment: @Aryerez, they have 3 columns and more than 1000 rows.

Comment: @LIONELJOSEPH I meant that you will add to the question a sample of them, like you did for the output, so we can see the headers. And if headers are different between files, please explain the logic for each different name.

Comment: @Aryerez  all the files have the same columns , I tried setting the index not helpful though 
 New_PID        stock   New_WAWI
DY-120010771 1 120010771
DY-120010796 2 120010796

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add filename as column name toa particular file, then add each file to dataframe.write dataframe to csv
(considering each file has a 1 column.Customize the column header as per your columns)

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
filenames=["C:/Users/sghungurde/Documents/server2.csv","C:/Users/sghungurde/Documents/server3.csv"]
i=0
while(i<len(filenames)):
    extracting filename from filepath 
    c1= (filenames[i].split("/")[4]).split(".")[0]
    reading csv file and assigning column name to header
    f1=pd.read_csv(filenames[i],names=[c1])
    adding file column to dataframe
    df[c1]=f1[c1]
    i+=1

print(df)
writing final df merging result to csv
df.to_csv("C:/Users/sghungurde/Documents/merge.csv",index=False)
```

output

```
     server2       server3
 209.10.31.50  609.10.31.50
 204.12.31.53  704.12.31.53
 203.12.31.53  903.12.31.53
 102.71.99.13  102.71.99.13
```

Comment: is it possible to add an index to the records? As we cannot add Index to a data frame

Comment: while we dump data frame to csv ,index is automatically get applied,if we don't want we can set index=False

Comment: df.to_csv("C:/Users/sghungurde/Documents/merge.csv")